# File handle left behind by C++ code in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to debug an issue in my code. I have a process A which runs continuously till I ask it to stop.

Inside A I do the following:

- mount partition /dev/sda1
- `open()` // creates an empty file X
- `write()` // write some bytes to it
- `close()` // close the file
- `processFile()` // Perform some operation
- `remove()` // remove file
- umount /dev/sda1

Note I test after each operation above if it was successful or not befor moving forward.
When I do `lsof | grep A` it shows the file handle of X being owned by process A. I also see it has a (deleted). This prevents me from umounting the partition. Why is this happening and how can I get around this issue?

**EDIT**: Thanks all. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
tarFileDesc = _pSysCall->open("test.tar", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);    
 if (0 > tarFileDesc)
  return false;

 ... some logging here

 // Write http stream to tar file, istr is an argument to my function     
 int read_buffer_size = 0;     
 buffer = new char[4096];     
 while (!istr.eof() && count < content_length)
 {      
    if ((content_length - count) >= 4096)
        read_buffer_size = 4096;
    else
        read_buffer_size = content_length - count;

    memset(buffer, 0, 4096);
    istr.read(buffer, read_buffer_size);
    std::streamsize in_bytes = istr.gcount();
    if (istr.fail() || istr.bad())
    {
        status = false;
        break;
    }

    if (write(tarFileDesc, buffer, in_bytes) != in_bytes)
    {
        status = false;
        break;
    }
    count += in_bytes;
}
// Cleanup buffer
delete[] buffer;

if ((0 > tarFileDesc) && (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;   

if (0 != system("tar C /test -xvf test.tar"))
    return false;

if (0 != remove("test.tar"))
      return false;
```

Note I even tried just doing the open, close and remove. But I still see the handle being held by process.

Comment: Please add code, not meta-code. Locking problems can't usually be solved by meta-code. Boil down the original code, then we can try to debug it.

Comment: You see the file handle of file X being owned by your process *after* you deleted the file? I'm not an expert, but that sounds strange. Could you pack your problem in a few lines of code?

Comment: @mkluwe -- UNIXes support this behaviour. The same or a different process can delete file <x> whilst it's open. The file can still be written to through the open handles, but as soon as all handles to the file are closed, the file is deleted. Any attempted new open's on a file in this state though are denied. So if the file isn't being closed fully or properly in the process, this would be valid.

Comment: Chris J: Thank you for clarification, this information is very valuable to me! I just wrote some test code to get this on my mind fully. If you've got some references for me to look this up, please provide them…

Comment: The best I can find in a five minute google is this page: http://andrew-gray.com/unixfaq/filesystem.shtml ... search for the para that starts: "Opening a file increments the Link count". No it isn't contraditory when it says impossible to delete -- note it says the file becomes unreferenced, i.e., the file exists but the directory entry for it has been deleted. It might give a starting point for more googling, but my google-fu this morning isn't good enough for a short scout. It's one of those things I've picked up over the years and never seen to seek any further references for :-)

Answer (score 5):

The issue lies in these lines:

```
if ((0 > tarFileDesc) && (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;
```

This will only close the file descriptor if `tarFileDesc < 0`. What you mean is if `tarFileDesc >= 0` then close it as it's a valid file descriptor, so try changing this code to:

```
if ((0 > tarFileDesc) || (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;
```

This way you return false if the file descriptor is invalid, otherwise you return false if you're unable to close it.

Comment: HA! That's what you get when you twist expressions to do a compiler warning's job. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
tarFileDesc = _pSysCall->open("test.tar", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0777);    
 if (0 > tarFileDesc)
  return false;

 ... some logging here

 // Write http stream to tar file, istr is an argument to my function     
 int read_buffer_size = 0;     
 buffer = new char[4096];     
 while (!istr.eof() && count < content_length)
 {      
    if ((content_length - count) >= 4096)
        read_buffer_size = 4096;
    else
        read_buffer_size = content_length - count;

    memset(buffer, 0, 4096);
    istr.read(buffer, read_buffer_size);
    std::streamsize in_bytes = istr.gcount();
    if (istr.fail() || istr.bad())
    {
        status = false;
        break;
    }

    if (write(tarFileDesc, buffer, in_bytes) != in_bytes)
    {
        status = false;
        break;
    }
    count += in_bytes;
}
// Cleanup buffer
delete[] buffer;

if ((0 > tarFileDesc) && (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;   

if (0 != system("tar C /test -xvf test.tar"))
    return false;

if (0 != remove("test.tar"))
      return false;
```

Note I even tried just doing the open, close and remove. But I still see the handle being held by process.

Comment: i'm not sure he can with his reputation?

Comment: To the OP ... you can delete this comment now; I've put this code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to post some code.  But here's a great trick for you - if you create a temporary file in Unix/Linux/Mac OS X, you can delete it IMMEDIATELY and you can still write to it, read it, etc, but as soon as you close it it will go away.  It will also go away if some error kills your program before you get around to closing it.

Answer (score 0):

This look suspicious:

```
if ((0 > tarFileDesc) && (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;
```

Looking towards the top of your code, you already do a check for `0 > tarFileDesc`, and if true return false right at that point. So I'm thinking that this part of the check is redundant? i.e., should this simply read:

```
if (0 != close(tarFileDesc)))
    return false;
```

Comment: Close... see Anacrolix' answer.

Comment: @DevSolar -- disagree; the check is still redundant. Why is it needed when the chek for tarFileDesc has already been performed and the function exited?

Comment: a good point Chris J, however the OP is using a C cleanup paradigm where he means mostly to check and uninitialize at the end of the function. if he was to change the function later the check for a valid file descriptor could again be needed. if anything i'd put it down to an oversight on the OP's part. the first check that the file descriptor is invalid should instead goto the cleanup section instead of returning.

Comment: @ Chris: You correctly remove the check, but for the wrong reason: Not redundancy was the OP's problem, but a wrongly written check.